# Mongo Wrong Dates

Tags: php, mongodb, mongoid

Why is mongoDB creating wrong dates for me.

```
> start=new Date(2011,12,23)     
"Mon Jan 23 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
> start=new Date(2011,12,24)
"Tue Jan 24 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
> start=new Date(2011,13,24)
"Fri Feb 24 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
> start=new Date(2011,11,24)
"Sat Dec 24 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongo's date object is the Javascript date object, and its months are 0-based (Jan = 0, Dec = 11).

```
2011/12/23 is actually month #1 (12-11) of year 2011+1 -> Jan 23/2012
2011/12/24 is actually month #1 (12-11) of year 2011+1 -> Jan 24/2012
2011/13/24 is actually month #2 (13-11) of year 2011+1 -> Feb 24/2012
etc...
```

and besides the point, there is no month 13 in the calendar, so in at least the 3rd case, you're feeding an invalid date in to begin with - it's only the JS spec is polite and tranlates that into "next year" for you that it works at all.

Comment: Oh ... thank you so much. Will it work in PHP like - $from = new MongoDate($startDate); $to = new MongoDate($endDate); //Both made from strtotime() ; $cursor=$summary->find(array('date' => array('$gt'=>$from, '$lt'=>$to)));

Comment: No. PHP's months are 1-based. You'll have to adjust between the two.